# Write a SSO application on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, saml, single-sign-on

I'm looking for a solution to implement a SSO (single-sign on) application, and this app need to be in python and run on **GAE** (Google App Engine). This applications needs to be implemented using the [SAML](http://saml.xml.org/about-saml) protocol, because Google Apps offers Single-Sign On based on SAML.

In my case I couldn't use OpenId because allow acces from external ID, and I need that my customers can login in my applications with only Google Apps accounts, then their accounts would be the ID. Once did the login they can access any applications offered by my company.

I saw the [Gheimdall](http://code.google.com/p/gheimdall/), but I couldn't install it completely to test, this applications is much complicated to make a proof of concept project, the last release was in 2008 and their documentation is poor.

Anyone knows a solution or tip to my problem?

Comment: Can't you just use OpenID or Google Accounts signin for your app? You need to provide more details.

Comment: @Nick: No, because I need to implement this using [SAML](http://www.pingidentity.com/resource-center/SAML-Tutorials-and-Resources.cfm)

Comment: Does this need to be a Python solution that runs natively within your app or are you willing to consider an On-Demand solution to support your SAML 2.0 requirements? --Ian

Comment: This need to be a python solution, but now I don't need more that my application runs on GAE(Thanks God), so I can found more alternatives... Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Diego - I work for Ping Identity. If you'd like more info shoot me an email and I can give you some more info off-line. ibarnett AT pingidentity DOT com

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [PySAML2](https://github.com/rohe/pysaml2/), it should work with App Engine:

> PySAML2 is a **pure python**
>   implementation of a SAML2 service
>   provider and to some extend also the
>   identity provider. Originally written
>   to work in a WSGI environment there
>   are extensions that allow you to use
>   it with other frameworks.

Comment: PySAML is a binding of a library in C and the Google App Engine doesn't support that.

Comment: @Diego: Ah, you're right. Most existing python SAML libraries require C extensions; however, I have done a bit more research and found a SAML2 implementation that appears to be written in **pure python**; see my revised answer.

Comment: where did you get this description of your answer? because I downloaded this project, and in the README file I found this:

"You also need xmlsec, which you can find here: http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/ "

There is the documentation too: http://packages.python.org/pysaml2/html/install.html

xmlsec is a lib in C, and pysaml2 needs that, so pysaml2 don't solve my problem =/

Comment: @Diego: I found the description in the [README.rst](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~roland-hedberg/pysaml2/main/files). It looks like Roland Hedberg has converted PySAML2 to a pure python implementation. Notice that the original README is last modified on 2010-04-17 and README.rst was modified today! Also, if you look in setup.py, you will see that the core dependencies are [decorator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) and [httplib2](https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/), which both are pure-python modules.

Comment: I downloaded that pysaml2 branch in development and I will try to use, thanks.

Comment: @PanosJee I gave up this implementation long time ago. GAE is too restrictive to implement such a thing, and my company has chosen another development environment.